# Laravel: send email on registration

Tags: laravel

I want to be able to send emails through the registration of my system. I have set up all the mailtrap information and included all my key imports. However im not sure if the actual way of sending the email is correct. I keep getting error: undefined variable email, see the code below:

```
    protected function create(array $data)
{

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
    Mail::to($data['email'])->send(new WelcomeMail());
}
}
```

I have imported welcomemail and the facades import so everything is good to go, however i am unable to send the email as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any code after return will not execute. Do all your logic and then return.

```
$user = User::create([...])
Mail::to($user)->send(new WelcomeMail());

return $user;
```

Comment: Hi so although my solution and your solution both worked, do you know why the actual email does not reach the senders inbox ?

Comment: @codingkid If you are still using Mailtrap than you won't be able to send mails to real email services such as Gmail. Mailtrap is only used for testing purposes. Are you at least getting them in your Mailtrap inbox? If you want to send for real you can create a new google account and set credentials from Gmail in the env. Multiple tutorials on how to do that on the net.

Comment: no worries, i have resulted to using gmail, i have now been able to send emails across and receive them in the database, thank you for the help, i may have another query regarding the email stuff but it will be another question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61386023/laravel-send-user-name-on-email

Answer (score 1):

I also did:

```
  Mail::to($data['email'])->send(new WelcomeMail());
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
```

and this worked perfectly fine