# Laravel: send user name on email

Tags: laravel

So my email functionality can send emails to users. However i want to be able to send emails with the username that they enter when they register. For example 'Hello "john" ' in which john is the name entered. I have the following code:

RegisterController.php:

```
    protected function create(array $data)
{
    Mail::to($data['email'])->send(new WelcomeMail());
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

}
}
```

Welcome.blade.php

```
@component('mail::message')

Welcome to the Hotel Booking System {{$data->name}}

 The body of your message.



  Thanks,<br>
    {{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

Now in the welcome.blade.php is where i am receiving the error message of Undefined Variable $name. How would i fix this using the two pieces of code.

Comment: How did you pass the $name to your view file?

Comment: see the controller is to register a user, so i would have thought it would automatically pass through the $name

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#view-data

Comment: see updated i have updated the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to pass data into **WelcomeMail()**

```
Mail::to($data['email'])->send(new WelcomeMail($data['name']));
```

Inside WelcomeMail class

```
public $name;

public function __construct($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
}
```

Than you can access name  variable inside your markdown

```
Welcome to the Hotel Booking System {{$name}}
```

If you want to pass whole $data array into constructor

```
send(new WelcomeMail($data);
```

You can do this

```
public $data;

public function __construct($data)
{
    $this->data = $data;
}
```

Or

```
public $name, $email;

public function __construct($data)
{
    $this->name = $data['name];
    $this->email = $data['email];
}
```

You can also pass each value separately

```
send(new WelcomeMail($data['name'], $data['email']);
```

```
public function __construct($name, $email)
{
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->email = $email;
}
```

Comment: so if i were to pass multiple values say email for example, id have to create a new variable and add that to the construct parameters#

Comment: @codingkid it is mostly up to you. In this situation where multiple values come from the same source, I would rather send the whole $data array or even better the user object from the answer I gave you in the first question

Comment: ofc so in my array it will be ($data['name']['date'] etc, im more intrigued by the construct method, how would i place multiple values in the construct function, would it simply be __construct($name, $date ...) then; $this... for all variables defined ?

Comment: ah dude you're awsome thank you so much, think my project is now complete thanks to you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212352/discussion-between-codingkid-and-dino-numic).